# How to catch all exceptions in Web API 2?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

I'm writing a RESTful API in Web API and I'm not sure how to handle errors effectively.  I want the API to return JSON, and it needs to consist of the exact same format every single time - even on errors.  Here are a couple of examples of what a successful and a failed response might look like.

Success:

```
{
    Status: 0,
    Message: "Success",
    Data: {...}
}
```

Error:

```
{
    Status: 1,
    Message: "An error occurred!",
    Data: null
}
```

If there is an exception - *any* exception at all, I want to return a response that is formed like the second one.  What is the foolproof way to do this, so that no exceptions are left unhandled?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Implement `IExceptionHandler`.

Something like:

```
 public class APIErrorHandler : IExceptionHandler
 {
     public Task HandleAsync(ExceptionHandlerContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     {
         var customObject = new CustomObject
             {
                 Message = new { Message = context.Exception.Message }, 
                 Status = ... // whatever,
                 Data = ... // whatever
             };

        //Necessary to return Json
        var jsonType = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
        json.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;    

        var response = context.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, customObject, jsonType);

        context.Result = new ResponseMessageResult(response);

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

and in the configuration section of WebAPI (`public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)`) write:

```
config.Services.Replace(typeof(IExceptionHandler), new APIErrorHandler());
```

Comment: This approach seems to leave `Content-Type` set to `text/plain`, rather than `application/json`

Comment: No it's not. Just checked it in my own code and it keeps returning `application/json`.

Comment: Is there any way to do this that uses content negotiation?

Comment: I had to add System.Runtime.Serialization attributes to my custom error response object to get XML. Without the attributes web api fell back to json.

Comment: @Fernando JS what did your change do? I didn't see any comments on the change (i.e. why is it different / what advantages does it have)

Comment: @Ofer Zelig These changes pass JsonType in CreateResponse, then return "Content-Type application/json" rather than "Content-Type text/plain". I tested in default Web API 2 configs.

Comment: This is nice. Just a thought though: in a public API, would you really want to expose event the exception message? Also, most complete implementations would also need a class implementing an IExceptionLogger to log the exception to a diagnostic trace

Comment: @dotnetguy : 1) That's an implementation detail; in code you can opt for returning a generic message to end users vs. detailed error to admins. 2) That's outside of the question at hand's scope.

Comment: It's nice to still call these things out clearly, I'm sure you'd agree that a lot of newbies look at the accepted answers only and must be made aware of caveats on stuff that needs to be done before rolling out code in production

Comment: @dotnetguy without checking I guess there are 100s of threads about this in Meta. My view is to answer a question and potentially supply caveats if such are directly inherited from the question or answer. I don't think SO should supply newbie-proof copy & paste answers. A) because People should learn; B) because you end up contaminating answers with collateral data that doesn't help those who need focussed answers to focussed questions. But that's just my view...

Comment: @NathanAldenSr If you want something that works with content negotiation, take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39892341/how-do-i-use-a-custom-formatter-for-json-serialization/39892671?noredirect=1#comment67082581_39892671. That deals with the normal format, but when returning HtpResponseMessage it will use the right message formatter (when registered).